# Activity calling a DialogFragment: Dialog does not always get dismissed

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

I have an Activity that calls a DialogFragment like this:

```
private fun showDeleteDetailDialog(itemView: View, categoryId: String, detailId: String) {
    val dialog = DeleteDetailDialogFragment.newInstance(categoryId, detailId)
    dialog.show(this@DetailsActivity.fragmentManager, "DeleteDetailDialog")
}
```

And this is the code for my DialogFragment (a click on the PositiveButton deletes an item in Firebase database):

```
class DeleteDetailDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    val categoryId = arguments.getString(ARG_CATEGORY_ID)
    val detailId = arguments.getString(ARG_DETAIL_ID)
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_detail)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, { dialog, id ->
                deleteDetail(categoryId, detailId)
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, { dialog, id ->
                // User cancelled the dialog
            })
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create()
}

private fun deleteDetail(categoryId: String, detailId: String) {
    // get the detail reference for the specified category
    val deleteRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("details").child(categoryId).child(detailId)
    // remove detail
    deleteRef.removeValue()

    // get the reference for the specified favorite, identified by detailId
    val deleteFaveRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("favorites").child(detailId)
    // remove favorite
    deleteFaveRef.removeValue()
}

companion object {
    private val ARG_CATEGORY_ID = "category_id"
    private val ARG_DETAIL_ID = "detail_id"

    fun newInstance(categoryId: String, detailId: String): DeleteDetailDialogFragment {
        val fragment = DeleteDetailDialogFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString(ARG_CATEGORY_ID, categoryId)
        args.putString(ARG_DETAIL_ID, detailId)
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
}
```

When I call the Dialog, the Dialog window pops up. When I then click Cancel (the NegativeButton) the Dialog disappears as expected. When I click Delete (the PositiveButton), the Dialog disappears, again as expected.

BUT, after a successful Delete, when I call the Dialog again, a click on Cancel does not immediately dismiss the dialog; instead, the Dialog box pops up again and only disappears after a second click on Delete. There seems to be an issue with the FragmentManager. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code above! Removing an item in Firebase database triggered an `onDataChange` event in my `ValueEventListener` which then called an `updateUI` function. Unfortunately, I had my `onItemTouchListener` handling `onItemClick` events (like my remove() instruction via DialogFragment) placed there, which worked fine as long as I didn't change any data in my Firebase database. But removing an item there triggered a loop that caused the "erratic" behavior of my code. The solution was to move the call to my `onItemTouchListener` (that handles onItemClicks) from the updateUI function to the onCreate section of my code. Huh, I learnt something!

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
 getDialog().dismiss()
```

**NOTE**

You should create a Custom Dialog within DeleteDetailDialogFragment .

```
class DeleteDetailDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

     override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    {
         val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container,false)
         return rootView
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        return dialog
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, neither does calling `dismiss()` or `dismissAllowingStateLoss()`.

Comment: I would like to point out that calling this Dialog from an Adapter class works flawlessly!

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps Kindly add this in your question section.

Comment: I have tried with a Custom Dialog. The result was the same. The strange behavior only happens if I actually access my Firebase database by calling `deleteDetail`.

Comment: @CEOtech4lifeapps Move ahead!